# Questions about auxiliary equation and particular integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning differential equations. When we are giving the general solutions to a differential equation, we give:
$y=Ae^{mx} + Be^{nx}$ Do we assume that the value that two roots added together that is also a root, or it is a truth, can we prove this?
The other question that has been confusing me is that, when we are having repeated roots, we would give our general solution this way:
$y=(A+Bx)e^{mx}$ . 
I asked my teacher why, it said that we need to have one more solution or one more root, so we add the other x; but, my question is, do we assume that there are always two distinct roots, why do we need to give it another root. This is the same when we are doing non-homogenous equations, when we have a repeated roots that are same as the $a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+b\frac{dy}{dx} + c = f(x)$ If the auxiliary equation has a repeated root with the f(x), we will also need to add an x when we are testing the particular integral.
These questions are confusing me, and I tried to search for the internet; but, I can't understand most of the parts. So I have turned to the forum.
Thank you very much for you guys' replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General Solution for the Homogeneous Case

Let's say $ay''+by'+cy=0$. We know that, by definition, $e^{\lambda x}$ is a solution to $y'=\lambda y$. So let's try $y=e^{\lambda x}$. This gives us:
$$a\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}+b\lambda e^{\lambda x}+ce^{\lambda x}=0$$
and, since $e^{\lambda x}\neq 0$ always
$$a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$$
By the fundamental theorem of algebra, this quadratic will have two solutions. We'll call these $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. So $y=e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and $y=e^{\lambda_2 x}$ are solutions.

Now, let's say $y=Ae^{\lambda x}$ Then we just get
$$Aa\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}+Ab\lambda e^{\lambda x}+Ace^{\lambda x}=0$$
which reduces to the same quadratic. Therefore, $Ae^{\lambda_1 x}$ and $Be^{\lambda_2 x}$ are also solutions.

Finally, let's see if $y=Ae^{\lambda_1x}+Be^{\lambda_2x}$ is also a solution. Substituting into the original differential equation yields:
$$a(A\lambda_1^2e^{\lambda_1 x}+B\lambda_2^2e^{\lambda_1 x})+b(A\lambda_1 e^{\lambda_1 x}+B\lambda_2e^{\lambda_2 x})+c(Ae^{\lambda_1 x}+Be^{\lambda_2 x})=0$$
which simplify to
$$A(a\lambda_1^2+b\lambda_1+c)+B(a\lambda_2^2+\lambda_2+c)=0$$
But, by definition, the left-hand side will go to zero since $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the roots of $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$.

Hence, if $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$, then the general solution is $$y=Ae^{\lambda_1 x}+Be^{\lambda_2 x}$$
(The fact we can add solutions like this is called the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle)).

Now, what if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$? You may be tempted to say that the general solution is $$y=Ae^{\lambda x}$$
However, this is *not* the case. Intuitively, we want to have two constants of integration as this equation is second order. Formally speaking, the solutions to a second order homogeneous linear differential equation like this should always form a 2-dimensional vector space.

So, we need to try a different function for $y$. The next obvious guess is $y=xe^{\lambda x}$ and, using the same methods as before, we see that this does indeed work (for $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ only, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195644/xe-lambda-x-is-a-solution-to-a-simple-second-order-differential-equation-on?rq=1) for why). Hence the general solution in this case is
$$y=(Ax+B)e^{\lambda x}$$
(again, this relies on the superposition principle).

## Non-homogeneous Case

Now, let's say we have $ay''+by'+cy=f(x)$. As you know, we solve this by first considering the complementary function
$$ay''+by'+cy=0$$
Then we try a particular integral by varying the parameters of $f(x)$. However, what if $f(x)$ is contained within the complementary function? Then adding a particular integral of $f(x)$ to the complementary function will not give us the general solution. For example, if $f(x)=e^{2x}$ and the complementary function is
$$y_{CF}=Ae^{2x}+Be^{3x}$$
then $y_{CF}+f(x)$ is still effectively just $y_{CF}$. So, we need to try a different particular integral. The simplest choice seems to be $xf(x)$, as this is not contained within $y_{CF}$ and is still based around $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your high quality answer. I just have time to look through it carefully, and it really helps

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)